# How can I profile a multithread program in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading, profiling

I'm developing an inherently multithreaded module in Python, and I'd like to find out where it's spending its time. cProfile only seems to profile the main thread. Is there any way of profiling all threads involved in the calculation?

Comment: Sounds like :"Manage multi thread from a thread " ? Leave `parallel` for `serialize` ?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Please see [yappi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/yappi/) (Yet Another Python Profiler).

Comment: Please note that while yappi seems like the correct answer, it is a C source code and needs to be built. There are no pre-built binaries on the project page.

Comment: @velis: You can use pip: `pip install yappi`.

Comment: Documentation anyone? how do I sort the results to retrieve top 10 total time consumers?

Comment: @Dejell there's this if you use it programmatically https://code.google.com/archive/p/yappi/wikis/apiyappi_v092.wiki

Comment: How do you save a file with Yappi?

Comment: Why don't you expand on your answer and include an example?

Answer (score 20):

Instead of running one `cProfile`, you could run separate `cProfile` instance in each thread, then combine the stats. `Stats.add()` does this automatically.

Comment: not great when the program is starting and stopping many threads over the course of the calculation - it requires instrumenting the whole program, potentially severely affecting the results.

Comment: what i mean is that the overhead of creating and saving the profile instance for each thread run might easily skew the results. i don't think it's possible to make Stats without saving to a file.

Comment: Profiling shows how much active CPU time process spends in each function. It's not affected by profiler. Of course it will affect overall performance.

Comment: 1) profiling just shows time, not active cpu time (try cProfile.run('time.sleep(3)').
2) Stats.add() isn't very convenient for thousands of calls (easy to run out of fds, 1000s of lines printed at start)
3) overhead on thread create is factor of ~1000

Comment: @vartec - Can you show how to override the `Thread.run` method? I am trying to implement the profiling from there, but it is not obvious for me.

Comment: @mark: basically you have two options, either extend Thread class or monkey-patch it. Monkey-patching isn't clean or elegant, but for debugging/profiling it's good enough.

Comment: Instead of monkey-patching the Thread.run method, you can use threading.set_profile instead. It lets you call any function before a thread is started.

Comment: Good answer but not all that trivial to implement. I've provided a working prototype below. Thanks for the idea - works great. IMO should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 6):

If you're okay with doing a bit of extra work, you can write your own profiling class that implements `profile(self, frame, event, arg)`.  That gets called whenever a function is called, and you can fairly easily set up a structure to gather statistics from that.

You can then use [`threading.setprofile`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.setprofile) to register that function on every thread.  When the function is called you can use `threading.currentThread()` to see which it's running on.  More information (and ready-to-run recipe) here:

http://code.activestate.com/recipes/465831/

http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#threading.setprofile

Answer (score 2):

Given that your different threads' main functions differ, you can use the very helpful `profile_func()` decorator from [here](https://translate.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/translate/src/trunk/virtaal/devsupport/profiling.py).

Answer (score 2):

Check out `mtprof` from the Dask project:

https://github.com/dask/mtprof

It's a drop-in replacement for `cProfile` that, if your threads are launched in the usual way and complete before your main thread, will roll-up their stats into the same reporting stats. Worked like a charm for me.

Comment: Not sure why, but mtpof showed much more reliable results for me. yappi seems to have ignored one thread completely.

Comment: mtprof has been archived and has had no commits for 5 years — is it still up to date?

Answer (score 1):

From 2019: I liked vartec's suggestion but would have really liked a code exemple. Therefore I built one - it is not crazy hard to implement but you do need to take a few things into account. Here's a working sample (Python 3.6):

You can see that the results take into account the time spent by Thread1 & thread2 calls to the thread_func().

The only changes you need in your code is to subclass threading.Thread, override its run() method. Minimal changes for an easy way to profile threads.

```
import threading
import cProfile
from time import sleep
from pstats import Stats
import pstats
from time import time
import threading
import sys

# using different times to ensure the results reflect all threads
SHORT = 0.5
MED = 0.715874
T1_SLEEP = 1.37897
T2_SLEEP = 2.05746
ITER = 1
ITER_T = 4

class MyThreading(threading.Thread):
    """ Subclass to arrange for the profiler to run in the thread """
    def run(self):
        """ Here we simply wrap the call to self._target (the callable passed as arg to MyThreading(target=....) so that cProfile runs it for us, and thus is able to profile it. 
            Since we're in the current instance of each threading object at this point, we can run arbitrary number of threads & profile all of them 
        """
        try:
            if self._target:
                # using the name attr. of our thread to ensure unique profile filenames
                cProfile.runctx('self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)', globals=globals(), locals=locals(), filename= f'full_server_thread_{self.name}')
        finally:
            # Avoid a refcycle if the thread is running a function with
            # an argument that has a member that points to the thread.
            del self._target, self._args, self._kwargs

def main(args):
    """ Main func. """
    thread1_done =threading.Event()
    thread1_done.clear()
    thread2_done =threading.Event()
    thread2_done.clear()

    print("Main thread start.... ")
    t1 = MyThreading(target=thread_1, args=(thread1_done,), name="T1" )
    t2 = MyThreading(target=thread_2, args=(thread2_done,), name="T2" )
    print("Subthreads instances.... launching.")

    t1.start()          # start will call our overrident threading.run() method
    t2.start()

    for i in range(0,ITER):
        print(f"MAIN iteration: {i}")
        main_func_SHORT()
        main_func_MED()

    if thread1_done.wait() and thread2_done.wait():
        print("Threads are done now... ")
        return True

def main_func_SHORT():
    """ Func. called by the main T """
    sleep(SHORT)
    return True

def main_func_MED():
    sleep(MED)
    return True


def thread_1(done_flag):
    print("subthread target func 1 ")
    for i in range(0,ITER_T):
        thread_func(T1_SLEEP)
    done_flag.set()

def thread_func(SLEEP):
    print(f"Thread func")
    sleep(SLEEP)

def thread_2(done_flag):
    print("subthread target func 2 ")
    for i in range(0,ITER_T):
        thread_func(T2_SLEEP)
    done_flag.set()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    args = sys.argv[1:]
    cProfile.run('main(args)', f'full_server_profile')
    stats = Stats('full_server_profile')
    stats.add('full_server_thread_T1')
    stats.add('full_server_thread_T2')
    stats.sort_stats('filename').print_stats()
```

Answer (score -6):

I don't know any profiling-application that supports such thing for python - but You could write a Trace-class that writes log-files where you put in the information of when an operation is started and when it ended and how much time it consumed.

It's a simple and quick solution for your problem.