# How can I profile memory of multithread program in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading, profiling, memory-profiling

Is there a way to profile memory of a multithread program in Python?

For CPU profiling, I am using the cProfile to create seperate profiler stats for each thread and later combine them. However, I couldn't find a way to do this with memory profilers. I am using heapy.

Is there a way to combine stats in heapy like the cProfile? Or what other memory profilers would you suggest that is more suitable for this task.

A related question was asked for profiling CPU usage over multi-thread program: [How can I profile a multithread program in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653419/how-can-i-profile-a-multithread-program-in-python)

Also another question regarding the memory profiler: [Python memory profiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110259/python-memory-profiler)

Comment: What do you not like about the solutions in those other questions?

Comment: @Falmarri, I am looking for a 'memory' profiler. First one is mainly a CPU profiler. The second one only works for a single thread.

Comment: The main feature of threads is that they share memory (in contrast to processes). How do you expect to profile different memory stats for threads that share all the same memory?

Comment: @scoffey heapy, the memory profiler, does not profile all threads as one. It only profiles the memory usage of the thread it run on. I am looking for a way to profile memory of the whole process. The same idea goes for the CPU profiler, the cProfile module. However, there is a way to combine profile stats of different threads with cProfile which is explained in the link I gave above.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are happy to profile objects rather than raw memory, you can use the [`gc.get_objects()`](http://docs.python.org/library/gc#gc.get_objects) function so you don't need a custom metaclass. In more recent Python versions, [`sys.getsizeof()`](http://docs.python.org/library/sys#sys.getsizeof) will also let you take a shot at figuring out how much underlying memory is in use by those objects.

Comment: This is great. Much cleaner than my approach.

Answer (score 3):

There are ways to get valgrind to profile memory of python programs: http://www.python.org/dev/faq/#can-i-run-valgrind-against-python

Comment: Never heard of valgrind before; will definitely check it out.

Comment: @funktku this is a standard tool for profiling memory usage and detecting memory leaks.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. What I was exactly looking for does not seem to exist. So, I found a solution-a workaround for this problem.

Instead of profiling memory, I'll profile objects. This way, I'll be able to see how many objects exist at a specific time in the program. In order to achieve my goal, I made use of metaclasses with minimal modification to already existing code.

The following metaclass adds a very simple subroutine to `__init__` and `__del__` functions of the class. The subroutine for `__init__` increases the number of objects with that class name by one and the `__del__` decreases by one.

```
class ObjectProfilerMeta(type):
    #Just set metaclass of a class to ObjectProfilerMeta to profile object
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        if name.startswith('None'):
            return None

        if "__init__" in attrs:
            attrs["__init__"]=incAndCall(name,attrs["__init__"])
        else:
            attrs["__init__"]=incAndCall(name,dummyFunction)

        if "__del__" in attrs:
            attrs["__del__"]=decAndCall(name,attrs["__del__"])
        else:
            attrs["__del__"]=decAndCall(name,dummyFunction)

        return super(ObjectProfilerMeta, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)

    def __init__(self, name, bases, attrs):
        super(ObjectProfilerMeta, self).__init__(name, bases, attrs)


    def __add__(self, other):
        class AutoClass(self, other):
            pass
        return AutoClass
```

The incAndCall and decAndCall functions use use global variable of the module they exist.

```
counter={}
def incAndCall(name,func):
    if name not in counter:
        counter[name]=0

    def f(*args,**kwargs):
        counter[name]+=1
        func(*args,**kwargs)

    return f

def decAndCall(name,func):
    if name not in counter:
        counter[name]=0

    def f(*args,**kwargs):
        counter[name]-=1
        func(*args,**kwargs)

    return f

def dummyFunction(*args,**kwargs):
    pass
```

The dummyFunction is just a very simple workaround. I am sure there are much better ways to do it.

Finally, whenever you want to see the number of objects that exist, you just need to look at the counter dictionary. An example;

```
>>> class A:
    __metaclass__=ObjectProfilerMeta
    def __init__(self):
        pass


>>> class B:
    __metaclass__=ObjectProfilerMeta


>>> l=[]
>>> for i in range(117):
    l.append(A())


>>> for i in range(18):
    l.append(B())


>>> counter
{'A': 117, 'B': 18}
>>> l.pop(15)
<__main__.A object at 0x01210CB0>
>>> counter
{'A': 116, 'B': 18}
>>> l=[]
>>> counter
{'A': 0, 'B': 0}
```

I hope this helps you. It was sufficient for my case.

Answer (score -1):

I've used [Yappi](http://code.google.com/p/yappi/), which I've had success with for a few special multi-threaded cases. It's got great documentation so you shouldn't have too much trouble setting it up.

For memory specific profiling, check out [Heapy](http://guppy-pe.sourceforge.net/#Heapy). Be warned, it may create some of the largest log files you've ever seen!

Comment: Unfortunately I am aware of both of these profilers and gave link to related questions that specifically talk about Yappi and Heapy. The problem is, yappi does not profile memory and heapy only profiles the main threads memory usage (more precisely the thread it is called from).

Comment: @KushalP. I tried Yaapi, I think it can not give my line-by-line execution time. Do I miss something?