# Profiling an application that uses reactors/websockets and threads

Tags: python, autobahn, yappi

Hi I wrote a Python program that should run unattended. What it basically does is fetching some data via http get requests in a couple of threads and fetching data via websockets and the autobahn framework. Running it for 2 days shows me that it has a growing memory demand and even stops without any notice.
The documentation says I have to run the reactor as last line of code in the app.

I read that [yappi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653419/how-can-i-profile-a-multithread-program-in-python) is capable of profiling threaded applications
Here is some pseudo code

```
from autobahn.twisted.websocket import  WebSocketClientFactory,connectWS

if __name__ == "__main__":
#setting up a thread

#start the thread
Consumer.start()

xfactory = WebSocketClientFactory("wss://url")
cex_factory.protocol = socket
## SSL client context: default
##
if factory.isSecure:
    contextFactory = ssl.ClientContextFactory()
else:
    contextFactory = None

connectWS(xfactory, contextFactory)

reactor.run()
```

The example from the [yappi project site](https://code.google.com/p/yappi/wiki/usageyappi_v092) is the following:

```
import yappi
def a(): 
    for i in range(10000000): pass

yappi.start()
a()
yappi.get_func_stats().print_all()
yappi.get_thread_stats().print_all()
```

So I could put `yappi.start()` at the beginning and `yappi.get_func_stats().print_all()` plus `yappi.get_thread_stats().print_all()` after `reactor.run()` but since this code is never executed I will never get it executed.

So how do I profile a program like that ?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to use twistd profilers by the following way:

```
twistd -n --profile=profiling_results.txt --savestats --profiler=hotshot your_app
```

hotshot is a default profiler, you are also able to use cprofile.
Or you can run twistd from your python script by means of:

```
from twistd.scripts import run
run()
```

And add necessary parameters to script by `sys.argv[1:1] = ["--profile=profiling_results.txt", ...]`
After all you can convert hotshot format to calltree by means of:

```
hot2shot2calltree profiling_results.txt > calltree_profiling
```

And open generated calltree_profiling file:

```
kcachegrind calltree_profiling
```

There is a project for profiling of asynchronous execution time [twisted-theseus](https://github.com/flowroute/twisted-theseus)
You can also try tool of pycharm: [thread concurrency](http://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2015/10/announcing-pycharm-5-eap-143-308-thread-concurrency-visualization/)

There is a related question here [sof](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582336/how-can-you-profile-a-python-script)
You can also run your function by:

```
reactor.callWhenRunning(your_function, *parameters_list)
```

Or by `reactor.addSystemEventTrigger()` with event description and your profiling function call.